# jQuery scrollTo top of div on scroll or view

Tags: jquery, html, css

On a full screen site I am working on i'm using `scrollTo` with links which lets the user scroll horizontally to the relevant DIV.

The user can also scroll down the site using the mouse wheel.

My question is how can I use jQuery to automatically align the fullscreen div to the viewport so as when the user scrolls down the site they don't have to do it manually.

I'm not sure how to tackle this. Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NORSE/YrfBJ/2/).

There is a similar effect on this [website](http://www.baccaratresidencesny.com/residences/living-room), if you scroll down and leave the fullscreen div half off the screen it will automatically align the div to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Ive made a simple script for one of my projects...
It uses a plugin to find out if you are scrolling up or down and then calculates top position of an element that has the same class that you entered( in this case `.height`).
U can find more info here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YMY4/1/)

Comment: Great plugin, works really good! Although it blocks being able to scroll down to see more of a div if the content goes beyond the fold.

Comment: yep thats a problem with this plugin :), its made to work with divs that have `height:100%`

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy, I think.. ;)
If user scrolls over 200 pixels, the rest will be scrolled automatically until reaching the target.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 200){
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $YOUR_TARGET_HERE.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? By the way, you have to replace "target" by a string which should appear in the URL or leave the animation end function completely out if you don't need this feature :)